# Open an Excel document with C++ builder

Tags: c++, excel, c++builder

I am trying to open an existing Excel document using C++ builder. but I am having an exception :

> Project project1.exe raised exception class EOlSysError with message "incorrect type of variable"

Here is the code I'm using :

```
try {
    vMSExcel = Variant::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
}
catch (...) {
    vMSExcel = Variant::CreateObject("Excel.Application");
}

vMSExcel.OlePropertySet("Visible", true);

Variant vFileName = "C:\\Users\mi\\Desktop\\classeur1.xls";

vXLWorkbooks = vMSExcel.OlePropertyGet("Workbooks");
vXLWorkbook = vXLWorkbooks.OleFunction("Open", vFileName);
```

The exception is thrown in this line :

```
vXLWorkbook = vXLWorkbooks.OleFunction("Open", vFileName);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You may be losing the "\m" in your path because the C language may convert it to a control character or non-printing *escape sequence*.  Try either "\\m" or "/m".  I recommend **always** using forward slashes.

Comment: You appear to have another typo as well: the ampersand (&) appears in the second code block you show but not in the first.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tried the "\\m" and "/m"  but I'm still having the same error

Comment: @BrettWolfington it was just a mistake ( I edited the post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM FIXED :

I changed the type of vFileName from Vaiant to String and added c_str() to OleFucntion as following

```
vXLWorkbook = vXLWorkbooks.OleFunction( "Open",vFileName.c_str());
```